# How do you implement a Background App Refresh Task to call GraphAPI every few hours?

Tags: swift, swiftui, background-task, widgetkit

I am trying to make an iOS widget which shows the recent news that is updated on a Microsoft Sharepoint Site.  I want to implement a code which fetches the recent news every few hours using GraphAPI in the background. However, my code does not seem to work.

I have added Background App Refresh Tasks to the AppDelegate file, but I am unsure about the specific timing for registering BGTaskScheduler. Here is my current AppDelegate file.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import BackgroundTasks

let taskWithIdentifier = "sample.board.refresh"


class PrintOperation: Operation {
    let id: Int

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }

    override func main() {
        print("this operation id is \(self.id)")
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    private let msAuthAdapter: MSAuthAdapterProtocol = resolve()
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ItemViewModel()
    
    @AppStorage("is_init") var isInit: Bool = true
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: taskWithIdentifier, using: nil) { task in
            self.updateAll(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
        }
        return true
    }
    
    private func updateAll(task: BGAppRefreshTask){
        Task{
            await msAuthAdapter.getlistsitems(areaID: "000", today: Dates(), categorynm: "aaa") { json in
                self.viewModel.extractValues(from: json.rawValue as! [String : Any])
            }
            
            await msAuthAdapter.getlistsitems(areaID: "000", today: Dates(), categorynm: "bbb") { json in
                self.viewModel.extractValues(from: json.rawValue as! [String : Any])
            }
        }
        
        let queue = OperationQueue()
              queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
              task.expirationHandler = {
                  queue.cancelAllOperations()
              }

              let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        array.enumerated().forEach { arg in
            let (offset, value) = arg
            let operation = PrintOperation(id: value)
            if offset == array.count - 1 {
                operation.completionBlock = {
                    task.setTaskCompleted(success: operation.isFinished)
                }
            }
            queue.addOperation(operation)
        }
    }
    
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        scheduleAppRefresh()
    }
    
    func scheduleAppRefresh() {
        let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: taskWithIdentifier)
        request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15 * 60) // Fetch no earlier than 15 minutes from now
        
        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        } catch {
            print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        if !isInit {
            BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: taskWithIdentifier, using: nil) { task in
                self.updateAll(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
            }
        } else {
            print("isInit:", isInit)
        }
        let config = UISceneConfiguration(name: nil, sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
        return config
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        if !isInit {
            sleep(1)    // debug
        } else {
            sleep(1)    // debug
        }
    }
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
            completionHandler([[.banner, .list, .sound]])
    }
}
```

Also, could you please instruct me on how to register BGTaskScheduler and how to test it on a real device? I have tried the following within lldb, but nothing was executed.

```
e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler]_simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"sample.board.refresh"]
```

Comment: Since you tagged SwiftUI start [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10142/) but there are a lot of issues such as misuse of property wrappers, mixing of Concurrency, completion handlers and OperationQueue

Comment: Thank you @loremipsum for your comment. Actually I have already watched the attached video and refered to the codes shown but did not work.